# How to create multiple sub-directories in one command from windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am in a directory in windows command prompt. I can create one sub-directory in a single command like the following:

```
md  /data/rs1
```

I also can create multiple sub-directories by a single command from Linux like:

```
mkdir -p /data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3
```

But I want to create multiple sub-directories in windows command prompt by a single command.

How to do that?

More specifically, I need the equivalent command for windows of the above linux shell command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By using trial and error method, I found that the following line serve my purpose:

```
md data\rs1 data\rs2 data\rs3
```

To convert from unix command, remove the first `/` and replace rest `/` to `\`.

Comment: Hey there ya go!  They added a feature and didn't document it (very well, if at all). :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It's documented in http://ss64.com/nt/md.html

Comment: @DavidPostill ss64 is not Microsoft. I'd expect (not really) they'd add it to `md /?`;)

Answer (score 1):

In Commend Line Interface you can create multiple nested directories by using this code:

```
mkdir -p data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3
```

without the slash symbol / before the first directory.

Answer (score -4):

For windows please try the following package.json

```
{
"name": "react-blur-admin",
"version": "0.11.1",
"description": "React Blur Admin - Styles And Components",
"main": "dist",
"scripts": {
    "clean": "RD /S /Q dist && md dist && md dist\\assets && md dist\\assets\\styles && md dist\\assets\\fonts && md dist\\assets\\img",
    "deploy": "npm run clean && npm run deployjs && npm run deploycss && npm run deployassets",
    "deployassets": "copy src\\assets\\fonts dist\\assets && copy src\\assets\\img dist\\assets",
    "deploycss": "node-sass -r src/assets/styles/app.scss dist/assets/styles/react-blur-admin.min.css && copy src\\assets\\styles\\bootstrap\\fonts\\* dist\\assets\\fonts",
    "deployjs": "babel -d dist src",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext js src/",
    "prepublish": "npm run deploy",
    "preversion": "npm run lint && npm run test",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test NODE_PATH=. ./node_modules/.bin/mocha test/.setup.js test --recursive"
},
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/knledg/react-blur-admin.git"
},
"keywords": [
    "react",
    "blur admin"
],
"author": "Consolidated Knowledge",
"license": "MIT",
"bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/knledg/react-blur-admin/issues"
},
"homepage": "https://github.com/knledg/react-blur-admin#readme",
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=0.14.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "lodash": "^4.7.0",
    "react-flex-proto": "^1.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.11.6",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint": "^2.10.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "estraverse-fb": "^1.3.1",
    "jsdom": "^9.4.1",
    "mocha": "^2.5.2",
    "mocha-sinon": "^1.1.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.4",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
}
```

}

Comment: how is json related to folder creation? How can you run the json file?

Comment: @phuclv the json file contains the commands that npm uses for running different scripts, and the scripts it is running during the process have commands included in the file.

Comment: the OP didn't tag npm in the question. Moreover you also didn't mention anything about it in your answer, so it doesn't help anyone